# Understanding C# Documentation for Identity Method

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, identity

I was working with a tutorial using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and wrote this line of code:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>>().AddRoleStore<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>>();
```

What I don't understand is how to read the documentation regarding generic methods such as `AddRoleStore<>`

If I go to Microsoft's [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilder.addrolestore?view=aspnetcore-7.0) I get the same information from Intellisense:
[Screenshot of Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGBBS.png)

Having said this, if you look at the code the same method can receive up to 3 "nested" generic types?? `.AddRoleStore<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>>();` The website only says 1!

```
public virtual Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilder AddRoleStore<TStore> () where TStore : class;
```

Maybe I just don't know how to read the documentation because maybe the answer is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.irolestore-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

I still can't figure out how to understand the docs without asking someone or going for a tutorial

Thanks!

Comment: `RoleStore<ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>` is just *one* type, which the method is declared to take. Sure, to write this one type you had to write 3 other types, but the method doesn't care.

Comment: This question isn't about Visual Studio. Please be careful not to add irrelevant tags to your questions. Be sure to read the descriptions of tags before you use them for the first time.